# ax.locator_params(nbins=k) does not work in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this simple piece of code where I try to plot simple graph while limiting number of x ticks. There are hundreds of items in `iters` variable and if they get plotted it would just create one fat black line.
However, `ax.locator_params` does not work and the number of ticks aren't reduced.
I have tried setting it on `plt` object, but no help.
I also tried specifying `x` and `y` axes in locator_params, but no help as well.
Finally, I have tried moving `ax.locator_params` before and after `ax.plot`, but nothing seemed to help. I am completely out of ideas.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20,10))
ax.locator_params(tight=True, nbins=4)
ax.plot(iters, vals)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you call `locator_params` after creating the plot, you get a warning *'set_params()' not defined for locator of type <class 'matplotlib.category.StrCategoryLocator'>*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`locator_params()` with `nbins=` is only supported for numerical axes where the tick positions are set via [`MaxNLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator).

To get the same effect with text ticks, the current ticks can be stored in a list (`get_xticks`) and then be replaced by a subset. Note that changes to ticks (and to limits) should be called after the main plot functions.

```py
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(xticks[::len(xticks) // 4]) # set new tick positions
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30) # set tick rotation
ax.margins(x=0) # set tight margins
```

Comment: You are a savior, indeed iters type was string